# Why does comma expression not work as expected when used as the placement argument?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, expression, standards

```
#include <new>

using namespace std;

void f(void*)
{}

struct A
{};

int main()
{
    A a;

    f((a.~A(), &a)); // OK
    new (&a) A();    // OK

    new ((a.~A(), &a)) A(); // error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
}
```

I think (a.~A(), &a) is a valid expression which can be evaluated to a pointer value, so it should be accepted as the placement argument, why is the result not so?

My compiler is VC++ 2013 RC. Is this a compiler bug?

**Update:**

I have summitted a bug to [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a compiler bug, the syntax is correct.

You can look at the grammar in the standard:

```
new-placement:
( expression-list )
```

And, `a.~A(), &a` is valid as an expression-list.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what's going on.  The `new` is getting a single argument: two expressions separated by the comma operator and surrounded by parentheses.  Not accepting it is still a compiler bug, though.  (I'm not sure on the validity of taking the address of a dead object.)

Comment: @CTMacUser: taking the address of a dead or not yet constructed object is valid, though the operations you can do with such an address are very limited since any attempt to dereference it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @CTMacUser: Yes, that is how the comma operator works, but its failing as a syntax error, so its not evaluating the operands at all.